# Asp.Net Core 6 Scoped Filter inject UserManager

Tags: asp.net-core, twilio-verify

I'm working on linking Twilio Verify into an Asp.Net Core web site.  I'm pretty sure I have to figure out how to access UserManager in the filter (constructor).  But, I don't know how to access it.

My VerifyFilter:

```
public class VerifyFilter : IAsyncResourceFilter
{
   private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _manager;

   public VerifyFilter(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
   { _manager = manager; }

   public async Task OnResourceExecutionAsync(ResourceExecutingContext context, ResourceExecutionDelegate next)
   { // cut just to make listing a bit shorter }
}
```

My program.cs file currently looks like this:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<VerifyFilter>();
```

What I don't know is how I get the UserManager so I can pass it in.

I have another scoped right above it and I had to do this to get Verification to work.

```
Configuration.Twilio twilio = new Configuration.Twilio();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IVerification>(t => new Verification(twilio));
```

So I'm sure it's just a matter of figuring out how to get UserManager to pass in as a constructor, but with MinimalAPI and .Net Core 6.0, I don't know where it is at.

My entire program.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using test4.Data;
using test4.Filters;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlite(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services
    .AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(
        options =>
        {
           // These will get updated to production versions later.
           options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
           options.Password.RequiredLength = 1;
        })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddScoped<VerifyFilter>();

builder.Services.AddControllers(op =>
{
   op.Filters.Add<VerifyFilter>();
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
   app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
   app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
   // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
   app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

You could try to register the filter via the following code:

```
//register the Identity service

//register the custom filters.
builder.Services.AddControllers(op =>
{
    op.Filters.Add<VerifyFilter>();
});
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
```

Comment: This seems to have the same issue...

InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type     'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[test4.Models.ApplicationUser]' while attempting to activate 'test4.Filters.VerifyFilter'.

It seems to all come down to how to get an instance of UserManager<ApplicationUser> to inject into the filter.

Comment: Can you post the relates code in the Program.cs file, in my sample the result is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK38Q.png).

Comment: I added the entire program.cs to the original question.  Also, I tried it with (Builder.Servcies.AddScopedVerifyFilter>() as listed above, and without.  If I have that line commented out, I can launch the app, but it immediately blows up with the error about not finding the type listed above.